# Autofocus of input inside a popover makes the page scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popover, autofocus, floating-ui

When I have a popover inside a scrollable area with any floating lib in react (`tippy`, `floating-ui`, etcetc), and I have an `input` with `autoFocus` inside the popover, the screen will scroll when the popover renders. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries like `floating-ui` or `tippy` position the element *after* it has been mounted. The popover will therefore position itself at for example `x: 0, y: 0` for a short period, and `autoFocus` automatically scrolls the page for the popover to fit in the viewport. This can be resolved by turning of `autoFocus` and instead calling `inputRef.current.focus({preventScroll: true})` right after the component has mounted

There are hackier ways like setting the focus on a `setTimeout` but that makes it more complex.